# Determine the width of the ScrollPane scrollBar or the width of the available viewing area

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I need to set the `Min`, `Max` and `Pref` width of the `Pane` contained inside of a `ScrollPan`e to a single value (preferably the size of the `ScrollPane`'s available viewing area).

If I just bind it to `ScrollPan`e width, once the `Scrollbar` appears on the `ScrollPane` it overlays some of the underlying pane.

Is it possible to somehow determine the available width inside of the `ScrollPane`(i.e. full width minus the `Scrollbar` width) and monitor it for changes?

Comment: see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47450072/8356718 get scallBar width.

Comment: see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47450072/8356718 get scallBar width.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer. I can use the `scrollPane.viewportBoundsProperty()`

Comment: or you could use the getter method `ScrollPange.getViewportBounds()`