# JavaFX FXML-SceneBuilder-Image-resizable

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

My question is, how does one achieve automatic resizing of images during manipulation with the size of the application window in JavaFX? Could be this done directly in SceneBuilder?

Comment: Related: [Resizing images to fit the parent node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630296/resizing-images-to-fit-the-parent-node) and [How to resize an image when resizing the window in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993550/how-to-resize-an-image-when-resizing-the-window-in-javafx)

Answer (score 3):

It would work with binding its `WidthProperty` and `HeightProperty` to the size of the window. Let's assume that the Node `root` reflects the window's size.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView();
iv.fitWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
iv.fitHeightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty());
```

Now it scratches with the parent's property (`root`). You can also choose the different Node or perform some of calculation to amend the size.

Comment: Where is the FXML in this?

Answer (score 3):

Not using a `ImageView`, but if you add a image as background image for a `Region`, that means the `Region` can be resized and so can the background image, if the appropriate settings are used. E.g. You could use the following CSS properties to include the stackoverflow logo in a `Region`:

```css
-fx-background-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a');
-fx-background-size: contain;
-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
-fx-background-position: center;
```

*(In the above code the property name and the value are seperated by `:` and the `;` is not part of the value. It's written as you'd write it in a rule in a css stylesheet.)*

You can replace `contain` with `stretch` to not preserve the aspect ratio. In this case you don't need the `-fx-background-position` property.

More info about the properties used can be found in the [CSS doc for `Region`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region)

This should work as long as you add it to the `Region` that is resized. If you want the image to be resized to the full scene size, you need to set the properties at root `Pane`.

Other than that you'd probably need to write a custom control. (AFAIK it's not possible to use expression binding from SceneBuilder.)

Comment: Is there a way to do it using only .fxml?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "only fxml". Of course you could use inline css. Also more recent versions of JavaFX seem to find the proper constructor, if you create a [`Background`](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/docs9/api/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html) with a `BackgroundImage`...