# resizable image view in javafx in scene builder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have an image in the anchor area. but i can't resize this image when resizing a window. and do not understand why I can not change this property to view images

[image]

Comment: In this case, the `FXML` simple tells how to layout the `ImageView`. If you want to resize the ImageView with a window, you will have to do some bindings in the `Controller`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630296/resizing-images-to-fit-the-parent-node

Comment: That check box tells you the value of [`Node.isResizable()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#isResizable()) which is not configurable outside of overriding the method in subclasses. The result of this method indicates whether or not the node will be resized when being laid out by its parent. An `ImageView` is not resizable in that regard. As Sedrick said, this behavior should be done in code in the controller class; this can be done through the `fitWidth` and `fitHeight` properties of `ImageView`.