# Is it possible to make a ImageView in JavaFX responsive?

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, 2d-games, resizable

me and some friends are having a project, where we try to programm a game in JavaFX. We´ve got a GridPane, thats growing with ImageViews inside to hold the map and the game character, etc. (The game character and enemies will have their own imageview, that we can move around in the gridpane.) So, our problem now is, that we want out pictures to get bigger, when the window is getting bigger also, but right now only the columns of the GridPane are getting more distance to each other. I tried to find a way to change that, but I am not sure, if it is possible, cause ImageViews only have "FitHeight" and "FitWidth" and no prefWidth/Height or maxWidth/Height, as far as I see. I also tried to put HGrow and VGrow on always or sometimes, but it didn´t work. We can´t resize them with checking the stages size and changing their size in proportion to it all the time, cause we´ve got more than 800 ImageViews in our map to display all the Images. 
Here´s my code:

```
         </image></ImageView>
  <ImageView id="sample" fitHeight="25.0" fitWidth="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="15" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="24" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <image>
            <Image url="@sample.png" />
         </image></ImageView>
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. (not your game, but something small explicitly written to demonstrate what you are after and doesn't work as you expect it to work)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630296/resizing-images-to-fit-the-parent-node) may be what you are looking for