# Is there an easy way to set up an Image that is growing / shrinking with the window size in JavaFX using SceneBuilder only?

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, scenebuilder, pane

I want a Pane that has an ImageView. When i resize the widow with my mouse, i want the ImageView also to grow or shrink.

Im only allowed to use SceneBuilder.

For some reason i just cant get it wo work. I was tweaking setting for about 4 hours, using different panes, different solutions, different options. It just dont work.

Is there an easy way to get an ImageView resized with the window using SceneBuilder ? It does not matter if i use a AnchorPane or Vbox or whatever as Parent.

Comment: To make an `ImageView` responsive like that will require some work in code (or possibly manual editing of the FXML file). Another option is to use a background image. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/58476162/6395627 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/12630296/6395627 (I would avoid binding the fit width/height properties to the dimensions of an ancestor).

Comment: Not sure if SceneBuilder allows expression bindings by now. If it doesn't you could create a fxml that does this, but not with SceneBuilder.

Comment: Are you allowed to specify a controller in `fxml` ?